# Centring a .png with a high z-index within a div

Tags: html, css, png, z-index, bootstrap-5

I want to have a .png image to be 1) exactly in the centre of a div, no matter the device size and 2) to be above another .png image in the same div. Here is my html:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div id="spinningDial">
     <img src="redphone.png" id="phone"/>
     <img src="RadialSlime.png" id="radial" class="rotate" style="width: 100%;">
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
 #phone {
      position: absolute;
      left: 67%;
      top: 45%;
      z-index: 10;
      opacity: 100%;
      width: 200px;
      }
```

The redphone.png is the image I'm referring to in my specifications above.

Using position: absolute; and z-index: 10; seems like the only way I get the .png to be above the other image, but it seems to place it outside the div. Whereas using, say, position: relative; with the same z-index displaces the png above the other image but keeps it contained in the same div.

This is the [web page](https://gardendontcare.ca/compost%20hotline/composthotline.html), if anyone wants to view the page source and see all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to put position relative to the parent to take the parent as a repair. Then to set a position of top and left to 50% to the phone, and as you see there, the position is not exactly on the center because of the picture dimensions. To fix this, you use then a transform to decrease top and left with half of picture's dimensions.

In final, you would have this in your CSS:

```
#spinningDial {
      position: relative;
}

#phone {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 10;
      opacity: 100%;
      width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adjusting the `left` and `top` to `50%`, but also add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`. Result:

```css
 #phone {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div id="spinningDial">
     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" id="phone"/>
     <img src="https://cdn.i-scmp.com/sites/default/files/styles/landscape/public/d8/yp/images/shutterstock_259160825.jpg?itok=y8bw_02m" id="radial" class="rotate" style="width: 100%;">
   </div>
</div>
```